# How to join different table using group by condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two different temporary tables.

This is an example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7d0539e15be76f61cd3219c1087e524f

You can check the example table when you run the code.

And this is my code for join table.

```
select cat01
    , cat02
    , avg(price) as prc
from temp01
where 1=1
and dt_day between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-05'
group by cat01, cat02
```

But, I didn't know join temp01(cat01, cat02, dt_day) and temp02(cat01, cat02, start_dt, end_dt)  .

My point is to create a result table by combining temp01 and temp02.

Please check my code.

Comment: Please add all necessary code directly into your question. Also be more specific on the problem you have

Comment: @juergend I edit it. thank you.

Comment: How would you compare `temp01.dt_day` and `temp02.start_dt`/`temp02.end_dt`? i.e., "Join these rows if `start_dt >= dt_day`"?

Comment: We need to see your expected results.

Comment: @GeomanYabes Yes, that's my issue.

Comment: @DaleK You can see results table https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7d0539e15be76f61cd3219c1087e524f

Comment: Two point, ensure the question is stand alone i.e. doesn't depend on a link. 2 How does the fiddle show the expected results if you don't know how to query them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to make `NULL` as zero and take the average because `avg` ignores `NULL` values and also your result shows that the tables should be joined using cat01 field too.

[image]

```
select t1.cat01, t1.cat02, start_dt, end_dt, cast(avg(isnull(price, 0)) as numeric(18,2)) price
from temp01 t1
join temp02 t2 on t1.cat01 = t2.cat01 and t1.dt_day between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-05'   --t2.start_dt and t2.end_dt
group by t1.cat01, t1.cat02, start_dt, end_dt
order by t1.cat01 desc, t1.cat02
```

Please see the db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=857650f1aff6c6480b9620a8f9be763d).

Answer (score 1):

Is this your required result?

```
select t1.cat01, t1.cat02, t2.start_dt, t2.end_dt, avg(isnull(t1.price,0)) avg_price from temp01 t1, temp02 t2 group by t1.cat01, t1.cat02, t2.start_dt, t2.end_dt
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% on what the request is, but using this might do the trick.

```
select *
from 
    (select cat01
        , cat02
        , avg(price) as prc
    from temp01
    where 1=1
    and dt_day between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-05'
    group by cat01, cat02)
inner join
    (select *
    from temp02)
on
    temp01.cat01 = temp02.cat01
and
    temp01.cat02 = temp02.cat02
```